# React ChartJS - Text diferent text in both sides of chart Version: 4.2.1

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, primereact

in my react application, i'm using the PrimeReact and i need to put on the right side of my stacked bar chart another text like this figma image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPVja.png)

How can I add the right quantity text?

i could not find any resolve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You may want to check out chartjs-plugin-annotation